# what is the better way to get distinct attributes from context object array into another context? (REACT, TYPESCRIPT, CONTEXT)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

What is the better/right way to get distinct attributes from context object array into another context.

In this example I tried get the distinct company in List and insert into context Company on every list change, but the value of context Company never change...

Example:
**List/context.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {useCompany} from "../Company/context";

interface List {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  company: string;
  ramal: number;
}

interface ListContextValue {
  list: List[];
  setList: (data: List[]) => void;
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const initialList: ListContextValue = {
  list: [
    {
      name: "",
      age: 0,
      company: "",
      ramal: 0
    }
  ],
  setList: data => {}
};

const ListContext = React.createContext<ListContextValue>(initialList);

export default function ListProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState<List[]>([]);
  const {company, setCompany} = useCompany();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setList([
      {
        name: "name 1",
        age: 1,
        company: "company 1",
        ramal: 1
      },
      {
        name: "name 2",
        age: 2,
        company: "company 2",
        ramal: 2
      },
      {
        name: "name 3",
        age: 3,
        company: "company 2",
        ramal: 2
      }
    ]); // Axios get here
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (company.indexOf({ name: list[i].name }) === -1) {
        setCompany([
          ...company,
          {
            name: list[i].name
          }
        ]);
      }
    }
  }, list)

  return (
    <ListContext.Provider value={{ list, setList }}>
      {children}
    </ListContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useList() {
  const context = React.useContext(ListContext);
  const { list, setList } = context;
  return { list, setList };
}
```

**Company/context.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

interface Company {
  name: string;
}

interface CompanyContextValue {
  company: Company[];
  setCompany: (data: Company[]) => void;
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const initialCompany: CompanyContextValue = {
  company: [
    {
      name: ""
    }
  ],
  setCompany: data => {}
};

const CompanyContext = React.createContext<CompanyContextValue>(initialCompany);

export default function CompanyProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [company, setCompany] = React.useState<Company[]>([]);

  return (
    <CompanyContext.Provider value={{ company, setCompany }}>
      {children}
    </CompanyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useCompany() {
  const context = React.useContext(CompanyContext);
  const { company, setCompany } = context;
  return { company, setCompany };
}
```